# Storing .css() In Object, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I am currently trying to save the original CSS values of an element in an object like so:

```
var xc = {
    "pos": {
        "ml": String($(this).css("margin-left")),
        "mt": String($(this).css("margin-top"))
    }
};
```

After the values stored, I then change the CSS styles of the element whose values I just stored.

When I try to access the original values from the object, I am returned the new CSS styles of the element.

For example, 235px is stored in the object, I then change the 235px of the element to 10px. The 235px of the element now becomes 10px.

Comment: I think  you want to clone an object. http://stackoverflow.com/a/122704/2166409

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: _"When I try to access the original values from the object, I am returned the new CSS styles of the element."_ Please, **please** show us how you're (1) changing the CSS of the element and then (2) trying to access the original values.

Comment: Also consider using [this overload](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyNames)

Comment: Also, why that weird `String`? jQuery's css function returns a... string!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily preserve the [`style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.style) values by attaching them to a jQuery selection using [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

```
var $ele = $('#ele');
$ele.data( $ele.prop('style') );
```

If you change the css of `$ele`, but want to access the original values, it would just be a matter of calling `$ele.data()[property]`.

For example, if you want to revert all CSS values to their original values, then you could just simply pass the object saved in data to [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties):

```
$ele.css( $ele.data() );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (just without String):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@1.9.1" data-semver="1.9.1" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div style="margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 20px;"
    onclick="var xc = {'pos': {'ml': $(this).css('margin-left'), 'mt': $(this).css('margin-top') } }; alert(xc.pos.ml + ' ' + xc.pos.mt);">Test</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/kIH2Df?p=preview)